# Srcset incorrect with Owl Carousel and ACF?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, images

http://preview.kirstymarks.com/

Im looking to integrate Owl Carousel into my theme, and ive created some custom fields with ACF in conjunction with srcset.

Im testing it and it appears the images arent rendering correctly and i think its my srcset set up. Ive created 4 different image sizes:

```
add_image_size('extra-large-img', 9999, 1600);
add_image_size('large-img', 9999, 700);
add_image_size('medium-img', 9999, 540);
add_image_size('small-img', 9999, 400);
```

And this is my srcset setup:

```
$image = get_field('slider_image_1');

$url = $image['url'];
$title = $image['title'];
$alt = $image['alt'];

<img
    srcset="<?php echo $image['sizes']['small-img']; ?> 200w,
    <?php echo $image['sizes']['medium-img']; ?> 600w,
    <?php echo $image['sizes']['large-img']; ?> 1200w,
    <?php echo $image['sizes']['extra-large-img']; ?> 1600w"
    sizes="(max-width: 700px) 100vw, (max-width: 768px) 92vw, (max-width: 992px) 600px, 900px"

    src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['snall-img']; ?>"
    alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>">
```

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Update screenshot of issue.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If this is pasted from your actual code, you have a typo in the `img src` - you're calling `snall-img` instead of `small-img`. If not - can you provide more specifics on what is not working? Do the correct URLs load? Backtracking, if you use `print_r($image)` are you starting with the values you expect?

Comment: Hi WebElaine, thankyou for the response and picking up on my typo. I will correct this. Im viewing this in google Chrome at 652px width there is a huge gap which suggests my image isnt loading hence why i think my srcset is wrong.

Comment: Hi WebElaine, I think i have resolved this. In the Owl Carousel setup i had a responsive setting. Removed this and it appears to have fixed itself :) Thankyou for responding.